# Как отобразить элемент WebView?

Tags: java, android

Создал Activity содержащий один элемент

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
</WebView>
```

Прописал его в манифесте, не забыв про `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

```
<activity
            android:name=".BrowserActivity"
            android:label="myBrowser">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

В обработчике нажатия на кнопку описаны взаимодействия для  Intent

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.ya.ru"));
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

В Activity2, содержащим WebView, добавил описание действия при создании экрана в методе OnCreate

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);

        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        wv.loadUrl(data.toString());
    }
```

В приложении, при нажатии на кнопку вызывается предложение с помощью какого приложения открыть - на выбор мои браузеры + мой Модуль,
выбираю мой модуль, происходит создание экрана, после чего сразу предлагается "Открыть с помощью приложения" как при нажатии кнопки, правда на этот раз отображается только браузеры, без моего модуля.

Подскажите где копать и в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: вам надо чтобы диалог выбора не появлялся?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, когда открыт Activity, содержащий webview элемент он не отображает сразу в нем страницу сайта, а предлагает **еще раз** выбрать приложение с помощью которого открыть сайт. Если нажать функциональную клавишу андроид "Назад" то отображается мой Activity, но без открытого сайта

Comment: @mamba0767, так таки нужно ли вам изначальное, первое, отображение диалога выбора браузера/вашего активити при первом посыле интента с адресом?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб при первом - да

Comment: Кнопка и WebView в одной активности находятся?

Comment: @BORSHEVIK нет, одна активность содержит кнопку - другая WebView

Comment: @mamba0767 Покажите код для активности с WebView

Comment: @BORSHEVIK я подправил вопрос, но на самом деле мог просто сообщить, что Activity номер 2 содержит только несколько строк с определением WebView